# How to clear previous data in an infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I have coded an infinite scroll. When the user scrolls it will load an additional 20 items which makes it a long list.

I want the scroll to loads new items and clear the previous items.

```js
var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');

// Add 20 items.
var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}

// Detect when scrolled to bottom.
listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight) {
    loadMore();
  }
});

// Initially load some items.
loadMore();
```

```css
#infinite-list {
  /* We need to limit the height and show a scrollbar */
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* Optional, only to check that it works with margin/padding */
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* Optional eye candy below: */
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id='infinite-list'>
</ul>
```

Comment: when I execute your code, the items kept increasing when I scroll down. Can you elaborate on what's the problem is?

Comment: @Fernand I want to when I scroll down the list only show 20 items

Comment: When the app  load the new items it have to remove the old items

Comment: So what you want to happen is that when the users scrolls to the bottom, the old items are deleted from the list and only the new ones stay?

Comment: @FrancoAltuna Yes

Answer (score 1):

If you empty the list before that, would it be ok?

```js
var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');

// Add 20 items.
var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  listElm.innerHTML = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}

// Detect when scrolled to bottom.
listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight ) {
    loadMore();
  }
});

// Initially load some items.
loadMore();
```

```css
#infinite-list {
  /* We need to limit the height and show a scrollbar */
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;

  /* Optional, only to check that it works with margin/padding */
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

/* Optional eye candy below: */
li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul id='infinite-list'>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you. But in your code. When I scroll down to bottom it don't load the new items. I have to scroll up and scroll down again.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the list every time loadMore() is called.

```
var listElm = document.querySelector('#infinite-list');

// Add 20 items.
var nextItem = 1;
var loadMore = function() {
  //Here we empty the list to remove the old results
  listElm.innerHTML = ''
  //And then load the new items
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = 'Item ' + nextItem++;
    listElm.appendChild(item);
  }
}

// Detect when scrolled to bottom.
listElm.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (listElm.scrollTop + listElm.clientHeight >= listElm.scrollHeight ) {
    loadMore();
  }
});

// Initially load some items.
loadMore();
```